# Perl: Input file data into current position of another file

Tags: perl, perl-module

i have two files for example

file1

```
abcd
```

file2

```
this is test
it is abcd but
```

i want to add abcd in between

OUTPUT

```
this is test
abcd
it is abcd but
```

I am able to compare file1 with file2 using regex and get postition where file1 content equals file2 line

like here .."abcd"is contained in "it is abcd but"

but how do i add abcd above it?This is just example. my actuall files are very big. I appreciate if u can help me in developing generalized script to use with other files.

Comment: Just to confirm, **file1** and **file2** both have a lot of lines, right? Because it seemed like **file1** only has 1 line in the example you've given.

Comment: By the way, can you post the code you've used to compare file1 and file2 with regex?

Comment: @doubleDown Surely no one would post a question that was as misleading as that. That would be like the difference between ... "How do I turn off the light..." and "...in New York City?"

Comment: OP did say the actual files are big. So I suspect the real situation might not be as straightforward as his chosen examples seem to imply.

Comment: @doubleDown I agree, that part is suspicious, but I assumed it was file2 that was big.

Answer (score 3):

This comes to mind (untested):

```
perl -nlwe 'if (defined($ab)) { s/^(?=.*$ab)/$ab\n/; print; }
            else { $ab = quotemeta($_); }' file1 file2
```

Explanation:

Switches:

- `-p` read files and print lines
- `-l` handle newlines

So first off, we get the line from `file1`, which is stored in `$ab`. Because we use the defined-or assignment, we only get the first value, which comes from `file1`. We use `quotemeta()` to disable meta characters. Then we simply check each line with a regex, and if the word appears, we add it first on that line, followed by a newline. The regex uses the beginning of line anchor `^` to set the insert point at the beginning of the line. Then we use a look-ahead assertion to make sure the line contains the word.

This is the script version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$\ = "\n";                 # output field separator 
my $ab;
while (<>) {               # read argument files
    chomp;                 # remove newline
    $ab //= quotemeta($_); # set $ab
    s/^(?=.*$ab)/$ab\n/;   # perform substitution
}
continue {
    print;
}
```

Comment: Your oneliner seems not work, I tested and the output contains two `abcd` lines first, then the expected ouput.

Comment: Yes, that's the drawback of not testing it first. But then again, this is only to show you a way to proceed. We need to use the `-n` switch instead, and not print the first line.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.

Each line is saved to $prev. When the next line matches /$match/ and there has been a previous line $prev,then print $match,then assigns the current line to the last line variable.

One-liner:

```
perl -nle 'if (defined($m)) {/$m/ and $prev and print $m;$prev=$_;print} 
           else { $m = quotemeta($_) }' file1 file2
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.14;

open FH_ONE, '<', 'file1'
    or die "Can not open: $!";

open FH_TWO, '<', 'file2'
    or die "Can not open: $!";

while (<FH_ONE>) {
    chomp;
    my $match //= quotemeta($_);
    my $prev;

    while (<FH_TWO>) {
        chomp;
        say $match if /$match/ and $prev;
        $prev = $_;
        say;
    }
}
```